# Merging values from columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Before I start, my disclaimer is that I'm very new to Python and I've been building a flask app in an effort to learn more, so my question might be silly but please oblige me.

I have a Pandas Dataframe created from reading in a csv or excel doc on a flask app. The user uploads the document, so the dataframe and column names change with every upload.

The user also selects the columns they want to merge from a html multiselect object, which returns the selected columns from the user to the app script in the form of a python list.

What I currently have is:

```
df=pd.read_csv(file)
columns=df.columns.values
```

and

```
selected_col=request.form.getlist('columns')
```

All of this works fine, but I'm now stuck. How can I merge the values from the rows of this list of column names (selected_col) into a new column on the dataframe such that `df["Merged"] = list of selected column values`.

I've seen people use the merge function which seems to work well for 2 columns, but in this case it could be any number of columns that are merged, hence I'm looking for a function that either takes in a list of columns and merges it or iterates through the list of columns appending the values in a new column.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want to do is more like an element-wise concatenation, not a merge.

If I understand you correctly, you can get your desired result with a list comprehension creating a nested list that is turned into a pandas Series by assigning it as a new DataFrame column:

```py
df['Merged'] = [list(row) for row in df[selected_col].values]
```